# Android On Boot Receiver Crashing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, boot

I have my phone connected to Eclipse but I can't see logcat until phone is "fully" booted and my receiver (application) crashes before that so I'm unable to debug it. I'm sure it has to do something with context and intents :

My receiver is crashing on boot because of context problems I'm sure :

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();               
    int hour = c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int sek = c2.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    int dan;
    int dodaj;

    milivreme = ((hour * 60 * 60 * 1000)+ (minute * 60 * 1000) + (sek * 1000));

    Cursor cursor = DatabaseManager.getAllData();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        do
        {               
    milibaza = cursor.getInt(3);
    razlika = milibaza - milivreme;

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 2, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + razlika, pendingintent);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Update, finally managed to catch the exception :

```
01-06 02:21:19.920: E/AndroidRuntime(7360): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.prva.OnBootReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Why are you keeping the answerers below guessing? Attach your logcat stack trace (the red output that happens when your app crashes, provided you have USB debugging on your phone (emulators do so by default)) and let that do the talking. Also, receivers have 10 seconds to do their work, I don't see why you have a while loop in there.

Comment: @A--C I already told you, read my first sentence. Logcat doesn't catch the error because I guess error happens before Logcat is able to catch it. I would be glad if I could post the Logcat.

Comment: Use adb logcat from the command line, that should be faster. You can also make an Exception handler that writes the exception to disk. Lastly, start fresh, you have so many things that can go wrong. Also, the Context is a Context, unless you're casting to something else down the line, that's not the problem.

Comment: And you can also change this receiver so it listens for a custom broadcast, then broadcast wherever. You have a decent amount of possibilities for a stack trace.

Comment: @A--C I updated my question with some more details!

Comment: Nice! `cursor` has a good chance of being null, so that's what I'd check out first. Also, since you did catch the exception, do you have a full log? If you do, there should be a line number somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Context context`, don't `Context contextic`.

```
private Context contextic;    //    NEEDLEES !
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();                
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int sek = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int dan;
    int dodaj;

    milivreme = ((hour * 60 * 60 * 1000)+ (minute * 60 * 1000) + (sek * 1000));

    Cursor cursor = DatabaseManager.getAllData();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        do
        {               
    milibaza = cursor.getInt(3);
    razlika = milibaza - milivreme;

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 2, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE); //CONTEXT ! 

    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + razlika, pendingintent);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }}
```

My question for you : why did you write `while (cursor.moveToNext());` (the thing is that you use semicolon after loop) ?

If my answer isn't helpful, give please stack trace.

Comment: ^ Yes. BTW. changed the context to what you said, still crashing on boot. (check edited question)

Comment: Did you register receiver in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes I did. I have this in my manifest : `<receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver">  
      <intent-filter>  
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>  
      </intent-filter>  
 </receiver>
    
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Answer (score 1):

You should just use context, replace contextic with context and you should be fine.

Comment: Changed to what you said, still crashing on boot (check edited question).

Answer (score 1):

As problem is not clear with your code but there are some suggestions for you .

1) your variables `milivreme`,  `milibaza` etc must be of long type instead of int.

2) instead of below code just use `milivreme = System.currentTimeMillis();` which gives current time in millisecond.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();                
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int sek = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int dan;
    int dodaj;

    milivreme = ((hour * 60 * 60 * 1000)+ (minute * 60 * 1000) + (sek * 1000));
```

3)  check if cursor is not null. before `cursor.moveToFirst();`

4) see this line>>

```
PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 2, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I edited my code and my question. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same crash on boot.

Comment: dude you dont suppose to cast   System.currentTimeMillis(); into int, you have to change your variable to long. You know limits of  int and long?

Comment: change everything related to time in long variable, you might inserting wrong values in database, brushup your java skills!!

Comment: Sorry, I just copy pasted too fast from here so...I know the limits and I know numbers getting stored everything is withing the limits. Anyway that isn't the main problem of course...updated my question. Still crashing

Comment: I can bet you dont know Java basics, else after mentioning three time that you should use long values to store time, int can not be use. and how do you know this is not the issue. 
Pardon me, I can not help you more. learn basics of Java first.

Comment: Because value that is stored for this testing purpose is 300000, don't tell me integer can't take that number?